# Line passing through a box (Python)

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, multidimensional-array, intersection, voxel

Using Python (2.7), how can I tell when a line is passing through a box made of 4 points?

For instance, let's say that I've constructed a cube of points:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import pylab
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

fig = pylab.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

sequence_containing_x_vals = np.array([0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1])
sequence_containing_y_vals = np.array([0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1])
sequence_containing_z_vals = np.array([0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1])

ax.scatter(sequence_containing_x_vals, sequence_containing_y_vals, sequence_containing_z_vals)
pyplot.show()
```

Now, let's say I have a vertical line passing from (0.5,0.5,-3) to (0.5,0.5,3). How can I tell if that line passes through my cube?

Comment: https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/minimal-ray-tracer-rendering-simple-shapes/ray-box-intersection

Answer (score 0):

This could be the kind of algorithm you are looking for.

First calculate the equations representing the planes of which the faces of the cube are subsets, and the pair of equations that represent the line.

Now calculate the points of intersection of the line with each plane by forming triples consisting of the pair of equations of the line plus the equation for the given plane, and then solving this system.

Test whether the any of the solutions are within the given line segment and within the edges of the cube.

I haven't found a handy solution for the two equations defining a line given two points. However, the following URL provides methods for obtaining a plane's equation given three points: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1156983/find-the-equation-of-the-plane-knowing-that-it-passes-through-3-points.